# Run task or batch file only after a hard reboot or start from being completely shutdown

Tags: batch-file, task, reboot

I'm attempting to make a batch file that runs on start up and reboots the computer ONLY IF the computer was hard rebooted or started from being completely shutdown. The reason for this is a value in an application I'm running is reset every time the computer is hard rebooted or started from being shutdown, the value however is saved on a soft reboot. So I'd like to make that change within the batch file and restart the computer normally so the value is saved.

Is there an if statement or something so that it can recognize a hard reboot or startup from shutdown vs a soft reboot? Perhaps I can setup a task instead?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you on? You could probably catch a hard reboot by scanning the event log and look for a specific event ID.

Comment: I'm running on Windows 7 Embedded Standard.

This is not the case at all. I'm running Logitech Webcam software and editing the values for the webcam. On a hard reboot only, one of the values resets itself. Unfortunately, it's a bug in their software after talking to their support, it won't be fixed anytime soon as I've seen the problem on their forums spanning multiple years. So yeah, not trying to get around any software license. Just want this value to stay.

Comment: What about starting __regedit.exe__, navigating to registry key containing the value, right clicking on registry key, clicking on __Permissions__ and making this registry key read-only for your account or system account depending on which account is used by the webcam application changing the value on hard reboot?